# Record audio straight to NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation

I need to record audio and get it directly to NSData, I tried to do the same with AVAudioRecorder but unfortunately it saves the recording to a file, and the process takes to much time for saving audio in file and then reading it to NSData, please help with some coding where i could save the audio directly to NSData object, thanks in advance.

My recording code:
`

```
printf("\nstart recording ...");
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:11400.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
[recordSettings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:8] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSettings setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
NSArray *arrayTempDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *soundFilePath = [[arrayTempDir objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString: @"/sound.caf"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:soundFilePath error:nil];
NSLog(@"\n%@",soundFilePath);
NSURL *newURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
NSError *error = nil;
audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:newURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",error);
[audioRecorder setDelegate:self];
if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord] == YES)
{
    audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [audioRecorder record];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:RECORDING_METERING target:self selector:@selector(stopRecording) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
[recordSettings release];
```

`

Comment: I also need to convert the recording into NSData quick, so that as a Binary Bytes as a Attribute I can save the recording into Core Data.

Comment: The only solution i found is using Audio Queue's. For you coolcool1994, thats the only solution too. Because there is no way to that with AVAudioRecorder, you should do some CoreAudio and receive the chunks with the callback, and then pass them to you'r database.

Comment: Yes, with your advice, I took a different approach. I saved the recordings into files and then saved the url of those files into Core Data as Strings. Now everything works perfectly. Thank you Florik.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking to do the same thing right now. I stumbled across Audio Queue Services -- this is an API that apparently allows recording audio straight into objects.

**Quote from Docs:**
*When you record using Audio Queue Services, the destination can be just about anything—an on-disk file, a network connection, **an object in memory**, and so on.*

**See Docs:**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005343-CH4-SW1

Comment: This is so complicated!!

Comment: @coolcool1994 all in a day's work .  Well maybe _3_ days work ..

Answer (score 0):

The API won't allow you to do it. How long does it take you to read the file? The only way I see to do it is to regularly pole the file and add whatever has been added to it to an NSMutableData as the recording goes on (adding size_of_file - size_of_mutable_data every time).

Comment: Maybe there is an other api, maybe implemented will permit me to do that !!

Comment: You can also look into Audio Queues and Sound Streams (part of core audio), you'll get callbacks when new data is available. This a bit more complicated though...

Comment: It's a reasonable shot at an answer and imo not downvote territory